# Get highest count number of array items from JavaScript object of arrays

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript object which is an object of arrays.  When I print it to console it looks like this image below.

- 3 Object keys 0, 1, and 2
- Each object key has an array as its value

I need to get the highest number of array items from the object as a count number.

Right now each one has 3 array items but in my app there will be a different number for each one and I need to determine which has the highest number of items and save that number to a variable.\

How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: A screenshot? Surely you know a better way to add content like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another one:

```js
function getHighest(obj){
  keys = Object.keys(obj);
  if(!keys.length)
    return 0;
  
  max = obj[keys[0]].length;
  for(i=1; i<keys.length; i++ )
    {
      if(obj[keys[i]].length > max)
        max = obj[keys[i]].length;
    }
  return max;
}

obj = 
{
  '0': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
  '1': ['a', 'b'],
  '2': ['a', 'b', 'c']
};

console.log(getHighest(obj));
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need?

```
var number = 0;
var box;
Object.keys(object).map(array => {
    box = object[array].length;
    if(number > box) {
        number = box;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do using `.reduce`

```
var obj = {0:[1,2,3,4],1:[3,4,7],2:[3,4,5,6,7,8],3:[5,6,7]};
Object.keys(obj)
.reduce(function(res,key){
  if(res.length <obj[key].length){
    res.highestKey = key;
    res.length = obj[key].length;
    res.arr =  obj[key];
  }
   return res;  

},{highestKey:null,length:0, arr:null})

// will give
//{highestKey: "2", length: 6, arr: Array[6]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `for in` loop.

```
var object={
0: [1,21,3],
1: [1,2321,3,123,213]
};
var number = 0;
for (var i in object) {
  if (object[i].length > number) {
    number = object[i].length;
  }
}
console.log(number);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an ES6 way:

```
var A = {
  0:[1,2,3,4],
  1:[3,4,7],
  2:[3,4,5,6,7,8],
  3:[5,6,7]
}

const returnGreatestLength = (arr) => {
    return Math.max(...Array.from(
             {...arr, length: Object.keys(arr).length}, (v) => v.length
           ))
}
```

Here is another: You can just put the code in functions.

```
var a = {
  0: [1,2,3,4],
  1: [3,4,5],
  2: [3,4,5,6,7]
}

var largestArrayLength = a[Object.keys(a).sort((x, y) => {
  return a[x].length < a[y].length
}).shift()].length
```

or another way:

```
var a = {
  0: [1,2,3,4],
  1: [3,4,5],
  2: [3,4,5,6,7]
}
a[Object.keys(a).reduce((p,c) => {
   return (p.length > a[c].length) ? p : c 
}, [])].length
```